# How to implement Spring Security 4 with SSO oAuth2

Tags: primefaces, spring-security, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

I am doing an application using Spring 4 and Primefaces 5 .
I want to implement Spring Security using the [SSO](https://global.download.synology.com/download/Document/DeveloperGuide/Synology_SSO_API_Guide.pdf) of my Synology server  which is based on a oAuth2 protocol.
Having never used Spring Security I lose a little to implement the oAuth2 SSO . If someone help me or just redirect me an example or tutorial , I will be grateful. I spent a long time searching the net but without success ...

Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: Please create a real title. It now is a summary of tags, but this question is going to be marked as 'off topic'.

Comment: I just change the title.